# Load tif file on Leaflet Map from input type=file

Tags: leaflet, javascript

How do I load a tif file from html input? So i get the tif file as a Blob from my input.

```
<input class="form-control" id="rasterdatenInput" type="file" name="rasterdaten" accept=".tif">
```

I tried to do this with the geotiffJS

```
const tiff = await GeoTIFF.fromBlob(files[0]);
const image = await tiff.getImage();

// Do some stuff to get the imageBounds

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map)
```

But then I dont get the bands and the map just shows the frame of the tif.

Then I tried it with leaflet-geotiff. But I don´t know what url I have to choose with this command. The Blob String doesn´t work there.

```
var layer = L.leafletGeotiff(url, options).addTo(map);
```

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

According to the leaflet-geotiff [documentation](https://github.com/onaci/leaflet-geotiff-2):

you can specify in the `options` paramater (of `L.leafletGeotiff`) to read fromBlob:

```js
 // Optional, override default GeoTIFF function used to load source data
  // Oneof: fromUrl, fromBlob, fromArrayBuffer
  sourceFunction: GeoTIFF.fromUrl,
```